# Tracking/Sending Custom Events in FB Analytics for Web don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-analytics

I work for a startup and recently we wanted to give the newest Web version of the Facebook Analytics for apps a try but have come up with a problem:

First of all, the web app is built with React so I put the Facebook's JavaScript SDK in a base.html, test that it worked on every page with the logPageView that comes by default in the docs. Until that point, everything seems to be working fine.

But when I tried to use my own custom event for example:

```
function logPostCreatedEvent() {
  FB.AppEvents.logEvent('postCreated');
}
```

And check the analytics to see the event had been registered it took too long to update the data or it wouldn't load at all. So my question is: Is there a way during development to make the events show up right away?

I check everything the official Facebook docs has and also check an introduction video on web tracking

Also, I couldn't fin any info about how to handle the analytics in a React App or for a SPA app so if you know any good tutorial or info source it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you make sure the FB is within the caller's scope? (Try to put a breakpoint and see if the object is accessible)

Comment: The events should show up right away in the Event Debugging section of the analytics site. Are you looking there?